# Generating separate plots for each unique subject ID by adding abline() and lines()

Tags: r, plot, line, longitudinal, abline

I am trying to plot (a kind of) longitudinal observations by ID adding some more informations. I followed what it is stated here
[Generating separate plots for each unique subject ID and save them in the working directory with the subject ID number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793130/generating-separate-plots-for-each-unique-subject-id-and-save-them-in-the-workin)
but basically I am stucked on some issues; after manipulating my initial dataset, I get:

```
dput(dati1[10:15,c(1,6)])
```

```
structure(list(OPERA = c("CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", 
"Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", 
"Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana"), Finanziato_cumulato = c(2.65e+08, 
9e+07, 1.9e+08, 3.14e+08, 7.16e+08, 8.31e+08)), row.names = c(10L, 
11L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(dati2[100:114,c(1,6,10)])
```

```
structure(list(OPERA = c("CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", 
"CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", "CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", 
"CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", "CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", 
"Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", 
"Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", 
"Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", "Catania - Metropolitana", 
"Catania - Metropolitana"), DataPubblicazione = structure(c(18955, 
19010, 19018, 19101, 19205, 18208, 17555, 16392, 16392, 17330, 
18710, 18878, 18989, 19216, 19220), class = "Date"), Pubblicato_cumulato = c("1673547.8", 
"1673547.8", "1673547.8", "1673547.8", "1673547.8", "384812358.81", 
"497236813.29", "498686813.29", "499936813.29", "499936813.29", 
"502296318.06", "502296318.06", "502296318.06", "504833868.06", 
"510713868.06")), row.names = c(103L, 93L, 95L, 92L, 98L, 105L, 
110L, 107L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 109L, 106L, 111L, 108L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(dati4[c(83,105),])
```

```
structure(list(OPERA = c("CALTAGIRONE - GELA Ripristino e ammodernamento", 
"Catania - Metropolitana"), Data_Commissario = structure(c(19123, 
18844), class = "Date")), row.names = c(83L, 105L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
lst1 <- split(dati1, dati1$OPERA)
pdf('CUP.pdf')
invisible(lapply(lst1, function(sub) with(sub,                                        plot(sort(DATA_GENERAZIONE_COMPLETO), sort(Finanziato_cumulato), type='l',pch=20, col='darkblue',main= OPERA[1]))))
dev.off()
```

to get a plot for every `dati1$OPERA`;

what I am tryng to add is

```
abline(v=dati4$DataCommissario,col='green')
```

(which is unique for every 'OPERA') and

```
lines(dati2$DataPubblicazione, dati2$Pubblicato_cumulato],type='l',col='deeppink')
```

inside the line for `plot()`, but until now no solutions came to me; should I `split(dati2)` and `split(dati4)` and neste `lapply()` two times to get `abline()` and `lines()` as I am trying to do?  Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a case where I think `lapply` gets in the way and leads to less clear code. I think this would seem much more straightforward in a `for` loop.

Comment: I can't run your code because your `dput` is incomplete. It should start with `structure(list(...` but what you posted starts with `"C29J04000010008",...`. It would also be nice if you could make the sample data smaller. In your code, it seems like you are using 5 or so columns, but I see 15.5 columns in your `dput`. Could you instead share `dput(dc2[1:30, c("Opera", "DataSiopeBDAP", ...)])` including only the relevant columns?

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for your reply, I edited my post trying to be more coincise as possible, I am quite concern about my issue since I have to find a solution for my project. I appreciate your help!